# how to upload a large size zip file to server in android using the progressing/streaming method?

Tags: android, file-upload, streaming

In my application I want to zip more images and the zipped file should get uploaded to the server using the HTTP connection. Now I have completed the zipping process. But due to the large file size I could not uploaded directly like an image upload.

Any one could you please share your ideas for the same? Is there any possibilities to achieve this? And please refer me if you knows any third party app for the same.

Thanks.

Comment: Are the images Jpegs?  If so, they're already compressed and zipping them won't give you extra compression.

Comment: Yes, Thet are jpegs and pngs.